# Wicket AjaxLink javascript handler shows strange behaviour

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

I have a `ListView` that displays a list of `Panel`s, one below the other. Every panel features a button (implemented via `AjaxLink`) that closes the panel and removes it from the list.

This is how the ListView is initalized and how the panels are created:

```
panelsList = new ArrayList<MyPanel>();
pnlContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("pnlContainer");

ListView<MyPanel> pnlItems = new ListView<MyPanel>("pnlItems", panelsList) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem<MyPanel> item) {
        item.add(item.getModelObject());
        item.add(new AjaxLink<Void>("pnlClose") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                panelsList.remove(item.getModelObject());
                target.add(pnlContainer); // repaint panel container
            }
        });
    }
};

pnlContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
pnlContainer.add(pnlItems);
add(pnlContainer);
```

This works so far - the actions that trigger adding new panels (usually also `AjaxLink`s) do what they should and the new panel is added and displayed correctly. But I have problems getting the close button to fully work.

Please see the following steps:

**1)** I start the server and navigate to the main page. The `ListView` is initially populated with one panel.

Close-button-code of this panel:

```
<a wicket:id="pnlClose" id="pnlClose7" href="javascript:;">Close</a>
```

Searching the page code for *pnlClose7* finds the following javascript code that makes the button work as expected:

```
Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"./?0-1.IBehaviorListener.0-pnlContainer-pnlItems-0-pnlClose","e":"click","c":"pnlClose7"});;
```

**Note**: I do not press the button now, if i would, it would work as expected (thoroughly tested).

**2)** I trigger an action that opens a second panel. The panel is displayed below the first one as expected.

Close-button of the first panel:

```
<a wicket:id="pnlClose" id="pnlClosef" href="javascript:;">X</i></a>
```

Close-button of the second panel:

```
<a wicket:id="pnlClose" id="pnlClose10" href="javascript:;">X</i></a>
```

But now, neither searching for *pnlClosef* nor *pnlClose10* finds some javascript code. The buttons (both!) do not work. I can still find the javascript code for *pnlClose7*.

**3)** I reload the page via pressing F5.

The button IDs change to *pnlClose1a* and *pnlClose1b*. Both IDs have javascript counterparts and work.

**4)** I press the first button (upper panel, ID *pnlClose1a*). The panel is closed as expected.

The remaining button's ID changes to *pnlClose1c*, again without a javascript counterpart. Javascript code for *pnlClose1a* and *pnlClose1b* is still present.

To make a long story short, the javascript handlers for my `AjaxLink`s seem to have shyness issues and only appear after I press F5 or reload the whole page in any other manner. I guess thats because repainting the `pnlContainer` changes the IDs of the current panels - but why is the linked javascript not updated at the same time? Is there anything I can change in my code to update the whole page without completely reloading it?

Wierd thing is that I am pretty sure this worked before... But I checked the whole class history and can't find any major change that would have triggered that. The `ListView`-code is mainly static since I added it.

Comment: Try setting to true: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.html#setReuseItems%28boolean%29

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that... Already tried, no effect. On an additional note, the page is set to `isVersioned() {return false;}`, if that makes any difference. But I tried with versioning and it does not work either. Same with versioning and reusing items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was had similiar problem. if you have any hardcoded javascript code in your page or panels html file (using <script> tag) remove it and set that js code in renderHead of your panel.

Comment: Quick and dirty test - I just removed every component that contains hardcoded javascript (none of the panels mentioned above affected). No effect :(

Comment: I found the solution, a completely unrelated (and innocent looking) component was pushing an empty javascript to the client upon creation. Not sure what the developer intendet with that push, but that broke the whole page. I'll accept your answer as it was the one pointing me into the right direction. Wicket seems to be sensitive to javascript ^^